HorizontalPager overscroll effect only shows on half of the screen
When using HorizontalPager, trying to swipe past the first or last page will show the overscroll effect to indicate there are no more pages to view, but the visual effect only covers half the screen regardless if swiping from the top half or bottom half of the screen.
If swiping right pass the first page, the effect only covers the bottom half of the screen.
If swiping left pass the last page, the effect only overs the top half of the screen.


Using HorizontalPager from androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.5
VerticalPager does not show any of these problems.
Code is pretty much copy pasted from the basic HorizontalPager sample from the Google docs
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/pager#horizontalpager
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HorizontalPager(
                state = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 2 }),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .border(5.dp, Color.Blue)
            ) { page ->
                Text(
                    text = "Page: $page",
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


This seems to be a bug that is fixed in 1.8.0.
As of the time of writing that version is still in alpha so you would need to either wait for the stable release or switch to the alpha BOM instead of the stable BOM:
androidx.compose:compose-bom-alpha:2024.11.00


How did you find out that it was fixed? Did you just try it? I found this issue on the Google Issue Tracker, but it's not marked as fixed yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/381993898

Yes, I couldn't reproduce the issue with the alpha BOM, only the stable BOM so I concluded it was fixed.

Using HorizontalPager from androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.8.0-alpha06 does do the trick, big thanks!
